# Why is setting default value for parameter not working in my javascript?

Tags: javascript, parameters, constructor

I want to set a default of 'small' if no options object is passed into my constructor:

```
var Plan = function(options){
  this.name = options.name || 'small';
}
```

but when I do this:

```
var smallPlan = new Plan();

console.log(smallPlan.name);
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

What am I doing wrong? Isn't this the idiomatic way to set default parameter values in javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of over complicating the code to check if options and name is there, check to see if the object is defined, if not, set it to an empty object.

```
var Plan = function(options){
  options = options || {};
  this.name = options.name || 'small';
}
```

Comment: love it - this makes more sense

Comment: Why are you creating a new object? that's not necessary. You're doing the same as I'm doing, except that you're _always_ checking if `options.name` exists, even if you just determined it doesn't.

Comment: @Cerbrus It makes sense if there are more than one option to check; it's also much more legible and cleaner looking.

Comment: @Cerbrus look at yours, you have define small two times. It is hard to read. Plus if the poster wants to add more checks, it really makes sense so you do not have to do that object detection bit over and over again.

Comment: If the user wants to add more checks, he really should be using a normal `if(options){}` block.

Comment: @Cerbrus that means he would have to double up the code! It would look like your explanation code which means doubling up the defaults. What I would really do is a extend method that loops through and adds the values from one object to another.

Comment: @epascarello: take a look at my last code block I edited in, just now. Wouldn't you agree that that's a clean way to do it?

Comment: @Cerbrus I rather see an extends type of solution: Basic quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/AprAB/2/

Answer (score 4):

`options` is undefined. You can't access `options.name` if `options` doesn't exist.

If you want to check for more than just one property, I'd suggest something like this:

```
var Plan = function(options){
    // Set defaults
    this.name = 'foo';
    this.title = 'bar';
    this.something = 'even more stuff';
    if(options){ // If options exists, override defaults
       this.name = options.name || this.name;
       this.title = options.title || this.title;
       this.something = options.something || this.something;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, I'd try this:

```
var Plan = function(options){
    this.name = options ? options.name || 'small' : `small`;
}
```

It's a little ugly, but you'll have to check if `options` exists, and if `options` has a `name` property.

What this does is:

```
if(options){
    if(options.name){
        this.name = options.name;
    } else {
        this.name = 'small';
    }
} else {
    this.name = 'small';
}
```